# Outlook 2016 - take one mailbox offline (disconnect from Exchange)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Outlook 2016 installed on my device; in the Outlook client I have 3 mailbox accounts e.g., point at 3 different exchange servers O365.

For one mailbox I would like to take it 'offline' or 'disconnect' it from the mail (exchange) server, i.e., so I can still access the mails locally but not connect it to the server anymore.

Is this possible without exporting and importing "backup" files?

Many thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cached Exchange Mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-Cached-Exchange-Mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c) enables you to work with items in your Exchange mailbox even when your network connection is slow or unavailable. Cached Exchange mode makes local copies of most, but possibly not all items. Also, it doesn't take the account offline as desired, and the [Work Offline](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-from-working-offline-to-online-2460e4a8-16c7-47fc-b204-b1549275aac9) is a global setting that affects every account.

What you probably should do is to [export email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-Outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91).

On Server Fault we are more interested in [migrations on a larger scale](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-migrate-multiple-email-accounts-to-Office-365-0a4913fe-60fb-498f-9155-a86516418842). This question belongs to Super User.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I suspected this. re: Server Fault vs Super User, thanks for the heads up, I wasn't aware there was such a group, noted ...

Answer (score 0):

From Article:
https://account.lfchosting.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=181

This worked to isolate and shut down one account from sending/receiving.

> When you want to stop using an email account with Microsoft Outlook,
>   you can disable the account so that you no longer receive emails. All
>   of your saved messages will remain intact, and you can change your
>   mind at any time. However, until you completely delete the account,
>   you will still be able to send messages from the account.
>
> Launch Outlook and click the "Send/Receive" tab.
>
> Click "Send/Receive Groups" on the ribbon, and then select "Define
>   Send/Receive Groups."
>
> Select the "All Accounts" send/receive group in the new window, and
>   then click the "Edit" button.
>
> Select the account you want to disable, and then clear the check box
>   next to "Include the Selected Account in This Group." Click "OK" to
>   save the change.
>
> Repeat the previous steps for any other send/receive groups displayed
>   in the list. Click "Close" once you have removed the account from all
>   the groups. Outlook will no longer receive mail from the account;
>   however, you can still send messages from the account at this point.

Comment: This does not quite do what is asked. Outlook will still connect to the Exchange server when it starts up and prompt for credentials.